# android:theme=“@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen” does not work when added to the app's manifest file

Tags: android, statusbar

I added the code

```
    android:theme=“@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen”
```

to the manifest and the status bar is still there. How can I fix this.

The thing I exactly want is remove the status bar no make it full screen because the app is already full screen but the status bar is covering a small portion of the app.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- ****
     **** Generated by AppToMaret on Fri Jan 04 02:15:02 EST 2013
     **** If you wish, you can update this file to your needs.
     **** If updating, it has to be done prior to clicking 'Create New .apk' button        
     AppToMarket
     **** However, please make sure that your updates WILL NOT break the functionality.
     **** For example, removing permissions, could cause runtime exceptions
     ****
-->
<manifest android:versionCode="1"
android:installLocation="auto" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.appbuilder.u28941p382992"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="false" />
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".AppBuilder" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name=".PushNotification.AppPushNotification" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name=".GPSNotification.GPSLocationMap" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".GPSNotification.GPSLocationText" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.CalculatorPlugin.CalculatorPlugin" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="ibuildapp.romanblack/calculator" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.CallPlugin.CallPlugin" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.ImagesPlugin.ImagesPlugin" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="ibuildapp.romanblack/images" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.ImagesPlugin.ImagesDetails" android:configChanges="orientation" />
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.ImagesPlugin.ImagesBottomPanel" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.ContactPlugin.ContactPlugin" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="ibuildapp.romanblack/contacts" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".PushNotification.AppPushNotificationReceiver" />
        <service android:name=".GPSNotification.GPSService">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </service>
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.WebPlugin.WebPlugin" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="ibuildapp.romanblack/web" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.CustomFormPlugin.CustomFormPlugin" android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="ibuildapp.romanblack/customform" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="Email" android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.EmailPlugin.EmailPlugin">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="ibuildapp.romanblack/email" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.EmailPlugin.addfile" />
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.EmailPlugin.dellfile" />
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.EmailPlugin.filelist" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.ECommercePlugin.ECommercePlugin" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="ibuildapp.romanblack/ecom" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.ECommercePlugin.ECommerceBuy" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.ECommercePlugin.ECommerceDetails" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" />
        <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:name="com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.MapPlugin.MapPlugin">
            <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="ibuildapp.romanblack/map" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.MapPlugin.MapBottomPanel" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.MapPlugin.WebViewer" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.MediaPlugin.MediaPlugin" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="ibuildapp.romanblack/media" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.MediaPlugin.MusicPlayer" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.MediaPlugin.VideoPlayer" android:configChanges="orientation" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.MediaPlugin.AudioPlayer" android:configChanges="orientation" />
        <service android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.MediaPlugin.BackGroundMusicService" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.TablePlugin.TablePlugin" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="ibuildapp.romanblack/table" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.TablePlugin.TableDetails" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.CouponPlugin.CouponPlugin">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="ibuildapp.romanblack/coupon" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.CouponPlugin.CouponDetails" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.CameraPlugin.CameraPlugin" android:configChanges="orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="ibuildapp.romanblack/camera" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="Facebook" android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.CameraPlugin.CameraFacebookSharing" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="ibuildapp/picture" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="Twitter" android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.CameraPlugin.CameraTwitterSharing" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="ibuildapp/picture" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.NewsPlugin.NewsPlugin" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="ibuildapp.romanblack/rss" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.NewsPlugin.FeedDetails" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.NewsPlugin.EventsNotification" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.NewsPlugin.EventsNotificationView" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.TwitterPlugin.TwitterPlugin" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="ibuildapp.romanblack/twit" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.TwitterPlugin.Description" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:label="TicTacToe" android:name="com.ibuildapp.username.TicTacToe.MainActivity" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.appbuilder.u28941p382992" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.appbuilder.u28941p382992" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.WebPlugin.WebPlugin" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.MediaPlugin.MediaPlugin" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.MediaPlugin.MusicPlayer" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.MediaPlugin.VideoPlayer" android:configChanges="orientation" />
        <activity android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.MediaPlugin.AudioPlayer" android:configChanges="orientation" />
        <service android:name="com.ibuildapp.romanblack.MediaPlugin.BackGroundMusicService" />
    </application>
    <permission android:name="com.appbuilder.u28941p382992.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.appbuilder.u28941p382992.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: As I said to put ** android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"** in the application tag,but its not there,can you please do this.   **<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">**

Answer (score 3):

**If you want to remove the status bar,then use this:**

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
```

**Instead of:**

```
android:theme=“@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen
```

This worked for me.

**EDIT:**

*You have to add it here:*

*Write this in your menifest file.*

```
  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />



<application
            android:icon="@drawable/logo"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
```

Comment: I don't remember exactly where I added it but it was in the android manifest file. I followed some guys instructions on where to put it.

Comment: Just tried it and no go with the android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"       I can post a link to the apk of my app if anyone of you guys want to try and help me out. That would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know exactly but I do know it can work for most android versions.

Comment: android:theme=“@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen is also working here mate. Are you getting any error on the logcat?? Give the sdk limit to your application like I edited the answer

Comment: change your target from 3 to 8 and leave 13 as it is